# Cómo hacer un for genérico que haga push con solamente 3 objetos en un nuevo array?

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, bucle-for

Necesitaría hacer un for genérico, que pushee 3 objetos por cada array. La información lo traigo via API. Esto lo necesito porque estoy usando un carousel y solo quiero mostrar 3 cards por slide.
Adjunto código actual que estoy usando, pero el problema es que en caso de tener 9 objetos en mi API, me faltaría agregar otro push and NewData y creo que esa no sería la mejor idea. Espero que me hayan entendido, un saludo

```
useEffect(() => {
    getNews()
      .then(function (response) {
        const total = response.data.news.length;
        const groups = total / 3;
        const newData = [];
        newData.push(response.data.news.slice(0, 3));
        newData.push(response.data.news.slice(3));
        setData(newData);
        console.log(newData);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        setError(error);
      })
      .finally(function (response) {
        setIsLoading(false);
      });
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de usar `.slice()`, te recomiendo [splice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice), dentro de un ciclo que se ejecute mientras haya elementos en el arreglo original:

```
getNews()
    .then(function (response) {
        const newData = [];
        while(response.data.news.length > 0) {
            // Elimina hasta 3 elementos del arreglo original
            // Y los agrega en newData
            newData.push(response.data.news.splice(0, 3));
        }
        setData(newData);
        console.log(newData);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        setError(error);
    })
    .finally(function (response) {
        setIsLoading(false);
    });
```